# Why can I pass a primitive to a method that takes an object?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, primitive, pass-by-value

Why is it possible to pass a primitive to a method that takes an object? Is the primitive turned into an object? like int = Integer and boolean = Boolean?

I can call the following function:

```
hash(41, 0);

    public static int hash(int seed, Object object)
    {
        int result = seed;
        if(object == null)
        {
            return hash(result, 0);
        }
        else if(!isArray(object))
        {
            result = hash(result, object.hashCode());
        }
        else
        {
            int length = Array.getLength(object);
            for(int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
            {
                Object item = Array.get(object, index);
                // prevent looping if item in array references the array itself
                if(!(item == object))
                {
                    result = hash(result, item);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling hash(int seed, Object object) with hash(41, 0)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is called a *boxing conversion*.  The `int` value is "boxed" into an `Integer`, which is an `Object`.  It has been available in Java since 1.5.

The [JLS, Section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) lists available boxing conversions:

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to
>   corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the
>   following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

Additionally, the boxing conversion is allowed during *method invocation conversion*, which is really what's going on here.  The value is being converted to another type because the `int` `0` is being passed to a method that expects an `Object`.  The [JLS, Section 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), lists boxing conversion as one method of method invocation conversion:

> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference
>     conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Something called [autoboxing/unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is done by the compiler automatically. Here is an excerpt from the docs.

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.

```
int i = 1;
Integer boxI = i; // Autoboxing is performed automatically by the compiler

Integer ii = 1;
int i = ii; // Auto(un)boxing is performed automatically by the compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, primitive is converted to Object and vice versa, and this concept is called boxing and unboxing. In newer versions of java this is done automatically, hence called, auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

[Oracle doc for Boxing and UnBoxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Each primitive has corresponding Wrapper class.

- int -> Integer
- boolean -> Boolean
- char -> Character

and so on.